# Ocultar Div con vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Alguien me podría ayudar, Como podría iniciar mi web con el div oculto y cuando presione el botón lo muestr, el div con JavaScript, codigo de lo que quiero ocultar esta así:

```
<div class="item1">
    <div class="imgPrincipal">
      <p id="pPrincipal" ></p>
      <img id="imgPrincipal" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

cuando haga click en el botón me lo muestre

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="inpSearch" />
  <button id="btnSearch" onclick="SearchPersona()">Search</button>
</div>
```

ya he ocultado el div por medio de css de esta forma

```
.item1{ display: none }
```

pero no he podido hacerlo aparecer con javascript

Comment: puedes cambiar su porpiedad style con js `element.style.display = none`, donde `element` es el elemento que has obtenido mediante `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí mi humilde aporte es con Javascript.

```js
const mostrar = document.querySelector("#btnSearch");
const mensaje = document.querySelector(".item1");

mostrar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mensaje.classList.toggle("item1");
});
```

```css
.item1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">
      soy el div oculto
      <!-- aqui va la imagen que quieres -->
    </div>

    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" id="inpSearch" />
      <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Buena forma, se me habia olvidado :c

Comment: Me funciono bien lo único que no se queda con el estilo que tenia antes pero funciona es lo que ocupaba muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Como dije en i comentario puedes hacerlo cambiando la propiedad `style` del elemento de esta forma

```js
elemento = document.getElementById("item1")

elemento.style.display = "none"
```

Eso ocultara el elemento, si quieres volver a mostrarlo solo lo cambias a `"block"`.
Tambien puedes hacerlo con la propiedad visibility.

```js
elemento = document.getElementById("item1")

elemento.style.visibility= "hidden"
```

Y lo muestras con `elemento.style.visibility= "visible"`

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar un div o img o lo que sea, cuando está oculto con CSS `display: none;`:

Con JavaScript se vuelve a mostrar lo que el CSS oculta:

```
  // Si es una clase
 document.querySelector(".item1")
// Si es una ID
document.getElementById("item1")
```

Con jQuery sería:

```
$(".item1").hide()
```

Pero hay otras opciones para hacer uso de CSS. Declaramos todo en CSS y activamos con JavaScript. Pero es más complejo

Comment: El titulo dice con *vanilla javascript*